# What iOS camera apps produce realistic HDRs?

Tags: ios, applications, camera

Many HDR photos have an over-processed look with colors that are oversaturated and otherwise [unrealistic](http://www.stuckincustoms.com), halos, excessive texture and local contrast, and so on. I don't like that.

What camera apps exist on iOS that capture realistic HDR photos?

They can use exposure fusion, or tone-mapping, or some other algorithm, as long as the result is natural-looking. I care about the result, not the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will stay posted since it requires a recommendation.

**I use VividHDR** and have dumped my desktop program for this gem.

**It uses 5 shots** unlike my previous 3 shot and the results are amazing. A user can still make it look unrealistic with tone-mapping settings but other than that I think you should look into.

---

**App features:**

**Full resolution HDR images.**

**Universal app**

**Take 3 or 5 bracketed shots** or just leave it to us to decide.
Intelligent algorithms to automatically analyze the scene and get the best exposures to capture details accurately in both highlights and shadows to deliver the best HDR image. You can get 7 stops of additional dynamic range over the regular camera.

**Fast processing**
vividHDR brackets, shoots and generates your HDR. Snappy fast. All this is done at the full resolution supported by the device and is always ready for the next shot.

**Presets and styles**
Control the look and style of your HDR image. Choose from a set of presets obtained from advanced tone mapping techniques. You also have the option to change the preset immediately after capture in the auto-preview mode.

**Sharp HDR images**
You do not need a tripod to capture great HDR images. Intelligent algorithms automatically compensate for camera shake. Advanced ghost removal techniques ensure that you get sharp images even with moving objects and fluttering leaves in your scene.

**Lazy HDR** 
Lazy HDR mode to capture now, style later. Change the presets and edit in non-destructive manner at any point of time for HDRs shot in Lazy HDR mode.

**Editing** 
Fine editing and post-processing controls for final touches to your HDR images. Controls for basic and advanced editing. 
Basic editing provides control over Brightness, Contrast, Saturation, Temperature and Tint of the image. 
Advanced edits such as Details, Highlights and Shadows allow control over the tone mapping process.

**Image formats**
Save images in JPEG format with good quality level. Additional option to store images lossless in TIFF format (lossless compression) ensure you don’t lose even those minute details.

**Gallery**
Feature to view your HDR images as a single photo, or a thumbnail view for fast browsing and group deleting. Compare your photos 'before-and-after' HDR. It also provides an option to save HDR images to Camera Roll.

**Picture information**
Supports EXIF and Geo-tag to save the location information.

**Sharing**
Share your pictures instantly to Flickr, Facebook and Dropbox, without having to leave the app. You can also E-mail the photo.

---

**Developers site:** http://www.ittiam.com/vividhdr/index.html

**Flickr samples:** https://www.flickr.com/groups/vividhdr/

[image]